# Print the ASCII character associated with a particular hex value

Tags: ruby, shell, hex

I know with Perl I can do things like this:

```
bash$> perl -e 'print "\x48"x40;'
=> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Trying to do this in Ruby:

```
bash$> ruby -e "40.times{ print("0x48") }"
=> 72727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272
....    
bash$> ruby -e "40.times{ print(48.to_s(16)) }"
=> 30303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030
....
bash$> ruby -e "40.times{ print('48'.hex) }"
=> 72727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272727272
```

How can I use Ruby in the shell with the `-e` option to print some count of a character, using a hexadecimal character, like `\x48` is `H`?

Comment: Is there a question there that I'm missing?

Comment: @theTinMan i just want print sequence of character by ruby using hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to print the ASCII character associated with a particular hex value like you did with Perl:

```
40.times{ print "\x48" }
# >> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

or

```
print "\x48" * 40
# >> HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

That means you can do:

```
ruby -e 'print "\x48" * 40'
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH
```

Ruby has a lot of Perlisms. In this case the use of `*` in Ruby is more consistent compared to Perl, which has `x` for characters and `*` for math.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following:

```
ruby -e "print('48'.hex.chr)"
```